# JavaFX add TableRow out of TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview, tablerow

I want show the TableView selection in a field out of the Table, so I thought I could add a TableRow out of the TableView and show it there, but I don't know if it's possible.

An object field would also do the job, but I haven't found a way to get that.

How should I proceed?

Comment: No, you cannot display a `TableRow` without a `TableView`. Instead, you would add `Label`s and other nodes to your scene and bind their values to the properties of the selected item in the `TableView`. There should be many tutorials and answers on SO to lead you in the right direction for that.

Comment: Here -> [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50653235/show-tableview-data-into-another-window-contains-textfield-in-javafx/50653518#50653518) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989771/populating-textfields-with-tableview-data-when-a-line-is-clicked/50990573#50990573) are some options for you.